# WPF: show all my object properties over my Combobox tooltip

Tags: wpf, combobox

So i have `ComboBox` binding with my `Person` object list and i want to show all my object properties over my Combobox `ToolTip`.

Currently this is what i try:

```
<ComboBox                                              
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Network inteface"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"                                                  
          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}">
          <ComboBox.ToolTip>
              <ToolTip>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
              </ToolTip>
          </ComboBox.ToolTip>
      </ComboBox>
```

And all i can see this is empty little line of `ToolTip`

Comment: Do you want to show all the properties of the currently selected item? Or do you want to show the properties for all items when you drop down the ComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your issue. You have some confusion. You want to show all information in tooltip of invidual item i.e. comboboxItem, instead of comboBox. In your posted code, you are trying to get information in tooltip of combobox.
For combobox item, Please go through following code

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedValuePath="Id">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

and here is result for reference

[image]